# Generate lognormal random numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random, probability-distribution

I'm trying to generate 10000 random numbers taken from a log normal distribution who's associated normal distribution has mean = 0.3 and std. dev. = 0.05 in MATLAB.

I'm using the built in `lognrnd` function.

My attempt is to do:

`R = lognrnd(0.3,0.05,10000,1)`

However, when I plot the histogram of `R` using `hist(R)`, the associated plot is normal, not log normal.

Where am I messing up? If the mean = 0.3 and std. dev. = 0.05 of the normal distribution, shouldn't the generated log normal numbers have a mean = 0.3 and std. dev = 0.05?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers you generate are actually from log-normal distribution. Plot just looks similar for your parameters. Compare `hist(R)` with `hist(log(R))` - the shape is pretty much the same.

As for mean and deviation, take a look at [lognrnd documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognrnd.html):

```
mu and sigma are the mean and standard deviation, respectively,
of the associated normal distribution.
```

hence generated numbers are expected to have different mean and deviation.

EDIT: I'm not sure if Matlab lets you specify lognormal distribution parameters directly, but you can derive one set of the parameters from the other. Assuming M and V are desired parameters of lognormal variable, you can calculate `mu` and `sigma` using following formulas:

```
x = 1 + V / M^2
sigma = sqrt(log(x))
mi    = log(M / sqrt(x))
```

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) for opposite conversion.

Comment: Okay - what if I want to generate random number from a log normal distribution which has a mean = 0.3 and std. dev = 0.05?

Comment: I would like to add that if you were to increase your sigma (to, say, .5) and use a more refined histogram `hist(R,100)` you would see something more like the skewed lognormal curve you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but I did a mistake in calculations. See updated formulas (I've tested them and results seem correct).

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** You can also do this easily now with the [Probability Distribution Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html#bum5reu) which gives you access to a broader range of functions (see the list at link provided).

Example provided using [`makedist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html) and [`random()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html).

```
N = 10000;                               % number of samples
pd = makedist('Lognormal',0.3,0.05)      % Probability Distribution Object
R = random(pd,N,1);                      % Call random()
```

As already pointed out, notice that

```
>> mean(pd)
ans =
    1.3515
>> std(pd)
ans =
    0.0676
```